# maven-assembly-plugin throws ambiguous NullPointerException

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I’m doing some refactoring of some existing projects - mostly we are moving from SVN to GIT and making a larger project more modular.  One piece I’m working on packages our native code into an assembly to be posted into our Artifactory so other projects can depend upon those native bits without having to build them.

So at this point… all I’ve done is taken the existing code and shuffled directories around, making them shallower, and then fixed up various scripts and paths to reference the new paths.  This all seems to work, however - when I go to build these assemblies, I receive a NullPointerError referencing the TarArchiver.cleanup() line 494, and no other aid as to indicate what might be wrong.

Can anyone provide any insight as to what might be going wrong, how I might better debug, etc?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sri</groupId>
  <artifactId>xsb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <artifact.basedir>${project.basedir}/../../build</artifact.basedir>
  </properties>


  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <!-- <descriptor>win32-x64.xml</descriptor> omitted for debugging-->
            <descriptor>cocoa-x64.xml</descriptor>
            <!-- <descriptor>linux-x64.xml</descriptor> omitted for debugging-->
          </descriptors>
            <detail>true</detail>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**cocoa-x64.xml (other descriptors are almost identical)**

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>cocoa-x64</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.bz2</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.properties.artifact.basedir}/trunk.osx/flserver-build/ext/XSB</directory>
      <outputDirectory>${file.separator}XSB</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**Debug Log**

```
xsb jklo$ mvn -e -X package
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/jklo/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /Users/jklo/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/jklo/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/jklo/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.sri:xsb:pom:0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.sri:xsb:pom:0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [package]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xsb 0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.sri:xsb:0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [sunflower (http://artifactory.sri.com/artifactory/sunflower-local, default, releases+snapshots), apache-snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots, default, releases+snapshots), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (make-assembly)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appendAssemblyId default-value="true">${assembly.appendAssemblyId}</appendAssemblyId>
  <attach default-value="true">${assembly.attach}</attach>
  <basedir default-value="${project.basedir}"/>
  <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>
  <descriptor>${descriptor}</descriptor>
  <descriptorId>${descriptorId}</descriptorId>
  <descriptors>
    <descriptor>cocoa-x64.xml</descriptor>
  </descriptors>
  <dryRun default-value="false">${assembly.dryRun}</dryRun>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
  <escapeString>${assembly.escapeString}</escapeString>
  <finalName default-value="${project.build.finalName}"/>
  <ignoreDirFormatExtensions default-value="true"/>
  <ignoreMissingDescriptor default-value="false">${assembly.ignoreMissingDescriptor}</ignoreMissingDescriptor>
  <ignorePermissions default-value="false">${assembly.ignorePermissions}</ignorePermissions>
  <includeProjectBuildFilters default-value="true">${assembly.includeProjectBuildFilters}</includeProjectBuildFilters>
  <includeSite default-value="false">${includeSite}</includeSite>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <mavenSession default-value="${session}"/>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <reactorProjects default-value="${reactorProjects}"/>
  <recompressZippedFiles default-value="true"/>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <runOnlyAtExecutionRoot default-value="false">${assembly.runOnlyAtExecutionRoot}</runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>
  <siteDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
  <skipAssembly default-value="false">${assembly.skipAssembly}</skipAssembly>
  <tarLongFileMode default-value="warn">${assembly.tarLongFileMode}</tarLongFileMode>
  <tempRoot default-value="${project.build.directory}/archive-tmp"/>
  <updateOnly default-value="false">${assembly.updateOnly}</updateOnly>
  <useJvmChmod default-value="false">${assembly.useJvmChmod}</useJvmChmod>
  <workDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/assembly/work"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=0, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=6}
[DEBUG] com.sri:xsb:pom:0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (make-assembly) @ xsb ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=2, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=248, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=51, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=9, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=125, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=668, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=13}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.5.3:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.22:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-alpha-6:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.6:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.21:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-repository-builder:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.5.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.22
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.6
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.21
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-repository-builder:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d6f6e28]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) appendAssemblyId = true
[DEBUG]   (f) attach = true
[DEBUG]   (s) basedir = /Users/jklo/projects/RAVE/source/sunflower-native/sunflower-native-build/floralib.artifacts/xsb
[DEBUG]   (s) descriptors = [cocoa-x64.xml]
[DEBUG]   (f) dryRun = false
[DEBUG]   (s) finalName = xsb-0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) ignoreDirFormatExtensions = true
[DEBUG]   (s) ignoreMissingDescriptor = false
[DEBUG]   (f) ignorePermissions = false
[DEBUG]   (f) includeProjectBuildFilters = true
[DEBUG]   (s) includeSite = false
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///Users/jklo/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@62d0ac62
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = /Users/jklo/projects/RAVE/source/sunflower-native/sunflower-native-build/floralib.artifacts/xsb/target
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.sri:xsb:0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/jklo/projects/RAVE/source/sunflower-native/sunflower-native-build/floralib.artifacts/xsb/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) reactorProjects = [MavenProject: com.sri:xsb:0.0.8349-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/jklo/projects/RAVE/source/sunflower-native/sunflower-native-build/floralib.artifacts/xsb/pom.xml]
[DEBUG]   (f) recompressZippedFiles = true
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [      id: sunflower
      url: http://artifactory.sri.com/artifactory/sunflower-local
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
,       id: apache-snapshots
      url: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
,       id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) runOnlyAtExecutionRoot = false
[DEBUG]   (s) siteDirectory = /Users/jklo/projects/RAVE/source/sunflower-native/sunflower-native-build/floralib.artifacts/xsb/target/site
[DEBUG]   (f) skipAssembly = false
[DEBUG]   (s) tarLongFileMode = warn
[DEBUG]   (s) tempRoot = /Users/jklo/projects/RAVE/source/sunflower-native/sunflower-native-build/floralib.artifacts/xsb/target/archive-tmp
[DEBUG]   (f) updateOnly = false
[DEBUG]   (f) useJvmChmod = false
[DEBUG]   (s) workDirectory = /Users/jklo/projects/RAVE/source/sunflower-native/sunflower-native-build/floralib.artifacts/xsb/target/assembly/work
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: cocoa-x64.xml
[DEBUG] Field directory source: ${project.properties.artifact.basedir}/trunk.osx/flserver-build/ext/XSB interpolated to: ../../build/trunk.osx/flserver-build/ext/XSB
[DEBUG] After assembly is interpolated:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <id>cocoa-x64</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.bz2</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>${file.separator}XSB</outputDirectory>
      <directory>../../build/trunk.osx/flserver-build/ext/XSB</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>



[DEBUG] All known ContainerDescriptorHandler components: [file-aggregator, metaInf-services, plexus, metaInf-spring]
[DEBUG] No ArtifactResolver with hint project-cache-aware
[DEBUG] FileSet[XSB/] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
[DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.511 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-06T17:24:42-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (make-assembly) on project xsb: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (make-assembly) on project xsb: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.tar.TarArchiver.cleanUp(TarArchiver.java:494)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:965)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:436)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:484)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was related to:

```
  <properties>
    <artifact.basedir>${project.basedir}/../../build</artifact.basedir>
  </properties>
```

I was off on the path by one `../`, hence my valid path should have been:

```
  <properties>
    <artifact.basedir>${project.basedir}/../../../build</artifact.basedir>
  </properties>
```

It's somewhat lame, for as long as this plugin as been around, that it doesn't provide better error handling for something as trivial as a bad path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the archive base directory is not set on the `maven-assembly-plugin` configuration. Please try to add the `<archiveBaseDirectory>` to the current maven assembly configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <archiveBaseDirectory>${project.basedir}</archiveBaseDirectory>

      <descriptors>
      ...
      </descriptors>
        <detail>true</detail>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      ...
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, with a different cause. My maven assembly plugin was creating a tar.gz in my build directory, and as I had built this project many times before, normally there was already an existing tar.gz in there that would be overwritten by the new build. Turns out I had been using 7zip to inspect the previous tar.gz. The file was still open in 7zip when I triggered the new build so the maven plugin wasn't able to delete the old tar.gz. Just another thing to be aware of for anyone looking at this question.